# "\end\end" causes "TeX capacity exceeded"

Tags: errors

I know this is invalid LaTeX code, but the code `\end\end` results in the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\end #1->\csname end#1
                      \endcsname \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@e...
l.1 \end\end
```

Why does this result in "TeX capacity exceeded" when this is simply invalid syntax?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is probably the shorter input for getting an infinite loop filling a part of the memory, but of course it relies on the definition of `\end` in the LaTeX kernel. With only primitives it should be `\def\a{a\a}\a`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not simply invalid syntax it is an infinite loop.

```
\end\end
```

is

```
\end{\end}
```

so it is the end environment call and it expands its argument

`\end` is more or less `\csname end#1\endcsname`  so that `\end{table}` executes `\endtable`.

so

```
\csname end\end\endcsname
```

so we have to expand the `\end` and get

```
\csname end\csname end\endcsname\endcsname
```

which is

```
\csname end\end\endcsname
```

and we loop and so on 500 times until you fill the input stack, each time `\endcsname` is taken as the argument of `\end` and re-inserted.