# Infinite loops in TeX

Tags: macros, tex-core

Some day I will learn how TeX actually works; in the meantime I ask here `;-)`

The code

```
\def\x{Hello!\par\x}
\x
```

gets stuck in an infinite loop, producing some thousands pages in a few seconds (as I expected). On the other hand, the snippet

```
\def\x{Hello!\x}
\x
```

results in the error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\x ->Hello 
          !\x
```

I would like to understand this behaviour. If I think just about macro expansion, I expect an infinite loop also in the latter situation: obviously this is not true, and issuing a new paragraph influences things.

Comment: Similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124423/end-end-causes-tex-capacity-exceeded

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When TeX sees `\par`, it makes a paragraph, building lines of text; when a sufficient number of lines is reached, it ejects a page and removes it from its memory. So it never runs out of memory with the first loop.

In the second case, it continues storing tokens until a paragraph ends. Which doesn't happen, obviously, before memory is exhausted.

It's important to note that when a macro is expanded, it is replaced by its replacement text and the original token disappears. However, the tokens `Hello!` are in both cases sent to the internal processor for building boxes.

Answer (score 19):

As egreg says the difference between your examples is the different size of the paragraph being built.

Just considering expansion there are other variants with different failure messages. TeX macro expansion uses *tail recursion elimination* so if a recursive call is the final item in the replacement the input stack is popped *before* the recursive call, and so there is no stack usage.

If you have

```
\def\x{Hello!\par\x\relax}
\x
```

which is a non tail-recursive variant of your first example, tex dies much earlier:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\x ->H
      ello!\par \x \relax 
\x ->Hello!\par \x 
                   \relax 
\x ->Hello!\par \x 
                   \relax 
\x ->Hello!\par \x 
                   \relax 
\x ->Hello!\par \x 
                   \relax 
\x ->Hello!\par \x 
                   \relax 
...
l.2 \x
```

and you get essentially the same error with the second version as the input stack is more restrictive than main memory

```
\def\x{Hello!\x\relax}
\x
```